# Dynamic class assignment in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, class, dynamic

I'm working on my post-graduate assignment where I have to create a simple calculator. I'm almost there but the final element - making the negative result red and positive green is still missing. The result must be seen in an input field

I was trying to use [ngClass]= with two conditions but it is not working:

```
<input type="number" [ngStyle]="resultStyling" value="{{ result }}" name="resultInput" 
[ngClass]="{
  'red': <=0,
  'green': !<=0
  }">
```

the public classes in component.ts for the calculator are:

```
public field1: number;
  public field2: number;
  public result: number;
  public isPositive: boolean = true;
```

The HTML:

```
<input type="number" [ngStyle]="inputStyling" name="field1" [(ngModel)]="field1"><br>
<button (click)="add()" [ngStyle]="buttonStyling">+</button>
<button (click)="substract()" [ngStyle]="buttonStyling">-</button>
<button (click)="multiply()" [ngStyle]="buttonStyling" >*</button>
<button (click)="divide()" [ngStyle]="buttonStyling">/</button><br><input type="number" [ngStyle]="inputStyling" name="field2" [(ngModel)]="field2">
<br>=<br>
<input type="number" [ngStyle]="resultStyling" value="{{ result }}" name="resultInput">
```

And the CSS are just 2 simple classes `.red {color: red} and .green {color: green}.

I can't figure out how to make the result show in color. Do you have any suggestions what may be the solution? Maybe the [ngClass] should just be written in a different way?

The whole code may be also found on my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/k-rapacz-angular-day1-z6vxu1

Thank you in advance for the support!

Comment: I don't do Angular, but `'red': <=0` looks suspicious. How is it supposed to know what should be tested against `0`? `'green': !<=0` looks even more suspicious, you might consider `>`. Finally, both of those conditions are trying to apply to 0. One of them (probably red) shouldn't include 0 (e.g., `<0` for red and `>=0` for green).

Comment: I know, right? I was trying to exchange it with {{ result }} <=0 but also with no success. @T.J.Crowder - thanks for the hints! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) there are multiple ways to conditionally add a class:

In your case you can do:

```
<input [ngClass]="{'red': result < 0, 'green': result > 0}">
```

or

```
<input [class.red]="result < 0" [class.green]="result > 0">
```

if you want 0 to have a color too, you can also just do:

```
[ngClass]="result < 0 ? 'red' : 'green'"
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/k-rapacz-angular-day1-8ahxxh?file=src/app/calc/calc.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

What about the `class.my-class` directive ? It applies the specified class to the element only if the condition is met :

```js
<input type="number" [ngStyle]="resultStyling" value="{{ result }}" name="resultInput" 
[class.red]="result <= 0" [class.green]="result > 0">
```

Answer (score 1):

Styles may be applied in the below way using Ternary Operator.

In you html last input, you can add a ngClass and add the styles based on ternary operator.

```
<input type="number" [ngStyle]="resultStyling" [ngClass]="result>0 ? 'green' : 'red'" value="{{ result }}" name="resultInput">
<br>
```

I the above code, we are checking if result is greater than 0 and, if yes, the green class is applied else, the red class is applied.

You can read more about applying classes [here](https://medium.com/@nixonaugustine5/angular-style-binding-26dd5e743339) .